# Create a list in a specific format? [ Or: Create a JSON file with specific format]

Tags: r, list, rjsonio

I am trying to create a JSON file with a specific format. My original approach was to reverse engineer the process by reading in a source JSON file using JSONIO, examining the resulting R list element and trying to recreate that list element with my own source data for use in toJSON. That approach was needlessly complex.  My restated problem is:

I want to create this JSON file:

```
{
 "items":[
   {"name":"Item 1","group":1},
   {"name":"Item 2","group":1},
   {"name":"Item 3","group":2},
 ]
}
```

From this input data:

```
name    group
"Item 1"   1
"Item 2"   1
"Item 3"   2
```

I will now focus more on the RJSONIO documentation. I was previously focused on recreating the R list with my data  instead of learning more about RJSONIO. Apologies for the misdirection.

The code snippet provided by @jlhoward below works well and is read by my application correctly. Is there a way to make the JSON more human-readable as in:

```
{
 "items":[
   {"name":"Item 1","group":1},
   {"name":"Item 2","group":1},
   {"name":"Item 3","group":2},
]}
```

Tim

Comment: You may want to look at `asJSVars()` and use the `.vars` argument

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What precisely in the input you will be using? You can convert a list to a copy/paste-able format with `dput(json_data)`.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. Your comment made me re-evaluate my approach and question. Question is now restated.     Richard - I will look more into the RJSONIO documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Calling your data frame `df`

```
library(rjson)
result <- toJSON(list(items=lapply(1:nrow(df),function(i)df[i,])))
cat(result)
# {"items":[{"name":"Item 1","group":1},{"name":"Item 2","group":1},{"name":"Item 3","group":2}]}
```

Comment: It is interesting to note the different format when RJSONIO is used instead of rjson: '{
 "items": [
 {
 "name": [ "Item 1" ],
"group": [      1 ] 
}, ...... etc.

Comment: this works well for my application.  Is there a way to make the output more human-readable, with each name and group on a separate line? I will update the original question to show the format.